# Getting error "uid 1000 not allowed to su" on RunTime.exec(“su”)

Tags: android

When I try to run a su command from my program, which has system rights, I got this error returned on stderr:

> uid 1000 not allowed to su

I'm setting shared uid to android.uid.system or android.uid.shell but it does not change a thing. The device is supposedely rooted. I really don't understand what happens.

Here is the code:

```
private boolean runAsRoot(String cmd, File workdir) throws IOException {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Execute command as root: " + cmd);
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", cmd});
    if (p == null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "cannot create process for " + cmd);
        return false;
    }

    int exit = -1;
    try {
        exit = p.waitFor();

        InputStreamReader isr;
        if (exit == 0) {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
        } else {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append('\n');
            }
            sb.append(line);
        }

        String string = sb.toString();

        Log.l(LOG_TAG, exit == 0 ? Level.INFO : Level.SEVERE, string);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e);
    }

    return exit == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a standard/official android 'su' program which is not intended to be usable for this purpose, rather than one from something like superuser.apk that has been modified to allow this.

You cannot (from a normal 3rd party app) set a shared UID to a privileged user such as system or even a semi-privileged one such as shell.

It is possible that your device has not yet been modified to allow root access at all.

Comment: Ok, that's possible. At least, ADB is root.

You can get the UID SYSTEM or SHELL by setting the Shared user ID to such and signing the APK with manufacturer's key and certificate (not a problem for me)

Comment: slash33, okay, i've done all of this, and did adb install, but still can not su. It says uid 1000 not allowed to su. Maybe i need somehow to install to the system folder, not just adb install?

Comment: Of course you cannot - **android is specifically designed not to let you** become root on production builds, or to allow application code to *ever* execute as such on *any* build.  If you want to try to exploit some security hole, you can try looking over on xda-developers, but that is beyond the scope of *this* website which concerns *software development*.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest would be to build your own nano "sudo" like this:

**sudo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    int i;
    int n = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        n += strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
    }
    char buf[n + 2];
    char* p = buf;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        strcpy(p, argv[i]);
        p += strlen(argv[i]);
        *p++ = i == argc - 1 ? 0 : ' ';
    }
    *p++ = 0;
    char* a[] = {"/system/bin/sh", "-c", buf, NULL};
    execve("/system/bin/sh", a, envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "sudo: /system/bin/sh  error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

compile and install it like this:

**make-sudo.sh**

```
export NDK_ROOT=~/<path to android-ndk>
export GCC=$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export SYS_ROOT=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-17/arch-arm
$GCC --sysroot $SYS_ROOT ./sudo.c -o ./sudo
adb root
adb shell "mount -o rw,remount /system"
adb shell "rm /system/xbin/sudo"
adb push  sudo /system/xbin/
adb shell "chmod 06755 /system/xbin/sudo"
adb shell "ls -l /system/xbin/sudo"
adb remount
rm ./sudo
```

**Warning:** *this is simple but dangerous approach because absence of sudoers file or any other black/white listing allows all other apps to use sudo. It was usable for me because my app it the only one on the embedded Android and no extra security is needed.*